# Need help in Fourier Transform

Tags: equation-solving, fourier-analysis

My code takes long time without results even with `Apart function` for this simple function.

```
IF = InverseFourierSinTransform[
  Apart[Sin[a w]^2/(a^2 w^3 (w^2 + b^2)), w], w, r, 
  Assumptions -> {r > 0, b > 0}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

Anyone know how to help or fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Using V 12.1:

With the assumption `Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0, 2a > t}` then progress is possible. These are the only ones I found that can make it integrate.

```
ClearAll[w, a, b];
zW = Apart[Sin[a w]^2/(a^2 w^3 (w^2 + b^2)), w]
```

$$
\frac{w \sin ^2(a w)}{a^2 b^4 \left(b^2+w^2\right)}+\frac{\sin ^2(a w)}{a^2 b^2 w^3}-\frac{\sin ^2(a w)}{a^2 b^4 w}
$$

Now

```
first = InverseFourierSinTransform[Sin[a w]^2/(a^2 b^2 w^3), w, t, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0, 2 a > t}]
```

$$
\frac{t (t-4 a)}{8 a^2 b^2}
$$

```
second = InverseFourierSinTransform[Sin[a w]^2/(a^2 b^4 w), w, t, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0,  2 a > t}]
```

$$
-\frac{1}{4 a^2 b^4}
$$

Now for the third term, it not as easy. `InverseFourierSinTransform` seems to hang on same assumption. So for a workaround, and assuming proper integral

```
if = Integrate[(w Sin[a w]^2)/(a^2 b^4 (b^2 + w^2))*Sin[w t], w, 
  Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0,2 a > 0}];
up = Limit[if, w -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0, 2 a > t}];
low = Limit[if, w -> 0, Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0, 2 a > t}];
third = Simplify[up - low]
```

$$
\frac{-i \text{Ci}(-i b (2 a-t)) \sinh (b (2 a-t))+i \text{Ci}(i b (2 a-t)) \sinh (b (2 a-t))+i \text{Ci}(-i b (2 a+t)) \sinh (b
   (2 a+t))-i \text{Ci}(i b (2 a+t)) \sinh (b (2 a+t))-2 \pi  \sinh (2 a b) \sinh (b t)-2 i \text{Ci}(-i b t) \sinh (b t)+2 i
   \text{Ci}(i b t) \sinh (b t)+2 \pi  \cosh (b t)}{8 a^2 b^4}
$$

Hence the over result is

```
first - second + third
```

$$
\frac{-i \text{Ci}(-i b (2 a-t)) \sinh (b (2 a-t))+i \text{Ci}(i b (2 a-t)) \sinh (b (2 a-t))+i \text{Ci}(-i b (2 a+t)) \sinh (b
   (2 a+t))-i \text{Ci}(i b (2 a+t)) \sinh (b (2 a+t))-2 \pi  \sinh (2 a b) \sinh (b t)-2 i \text{Ci}(-i b t) \sinh (b t)+2 i
   \text{Ci}(i b t) \sinh (b t)+2 \pi  \cosh (b t)}{8 a^2 b^4}+\frac{t (t-4 a)}{8 a^2 b^2}+\frac{1}{4 a^2 b^4}
$$

For `t > 0, b > 0, 2 a > t`. Note that `Ci` is `CosIntegral`

Where did the need to do this came up from? Was it a real physical problem or made up one?

I tried Maple on this, and it gives very quick and smaller result. But I have no idea now if it correct or not and it worked only using the assumptions `t>0,b>0`

```
restart;
Fw:=sin(a*w)^2/(a^2*w^3*(w^2+b^2));
inttrans:-fouriersin(Fw,w,t) assuming t>0,b>0
```

$$
-{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi} \left( -{t}^{2}{b}^{2}-4\,ta{b}^{2}-4\,{
a}^{2}{b}^{2}+{{\rm e}^{- \left( t+2\,a \right) b}}+{{\rm e}^{ \left( 
t+2\,a \right) b}}-2 \right) {\it Heaviside} \left( t+2\,a \right) }{8
\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}}}-{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi} \left( -{t}^{2}{b}^{2}
+4\,ta{b}^{2}-4\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}+{{\rm e}^{- \left( t-2\,a \right) b}}+
{{\rm e}^{ \left( t-2\,a \right) b}}-2 \right) {\it Heaviside} \left( 
t-2\,a \right) }{8\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}}}-{\frac {\sqrt {2}\sqrt {\pi}
 \left( 2\,{t}^{2}{b}^{2}+4\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}-{{\rm e}^{ \left( t+2\,a
 \right) b}}-{{\rm e}^{ \left( t-2\,a \right) b}}-2\,{{\rm e}^{-tb}}+4
 \right) }{8\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}}}
$$

Notice, [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/fourier) has no "inverse sine" Fourier transform. It is the same function `fouriersin` which does both due to symmetry.

Comment: sorry but what are you trying to do here `up = Limit[if, w -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0, 2 a > t}];
low = Limit[if, w -> 0, Assumptions -> {t > 0, b > 0, 2 a > t}];
third = Simplify[up - low]`?

Comment: @Johe this does the definite integration. The Fourier sine transform is from 0 to infinity.

Comment: Thanks! I have to look back to your approach.

Comment: I checked Maple answer with Mathematica, is correct,only Maple answer need  to multiply by: `-(1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])`.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
Using V 12.1:

```
func1 = Sin[B*a w]^2/(a^2 w^3 (w^2 + b^2));(* In this case B=1 *)
func2 = LaplaceTransform[func1, B, s] // Apart
func3 = InverseFourierSinTransform[func2, w, r, Assumptions -> {r > 0, b > 0}, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] // ExpandAll 
InverseLaplaceTransform[func3, s, B] /. B -> 1 // FullSimplify (* In this case B=1 *)

 (*(-4 a^2 b^2 + (2 + b^2 (4 a^2 - 4 Sqrt[a^2] r + r^2) - 
2 Cosh[a b (2 - r/Sqrt[a^2])]) HeavisideTheta[
1 - r/(2 Sqrt[a^2])] + 4 E^(-b r) Sinh[a b]^2)/(8 a^2 b^4)*)
```

Code in TeX format:

$\text{InverseFourierSinTransform}\left[\frac{\sin ^2(a w)}{a^2 b^2 w^3},w,t\right]=\\\frac{\theta \left(1-\frac{r}{2 \sqrt{a^2}}\right) \left(b^2 \left(-4 \sqrt{a^2} r+4 a^2+r^2\right)-2 \cosh \left(a b \left(2-\frac{r}{\sqrt{a^2}}\right)\right)+2\right)-4 a^2 b^2+4 e^{-b r} \sinh ^2(a b)}{8 a^2
   b^4}$